# Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Apache kafka connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have setup MSK cluster in aws and created an EC2 instance in the same vpn.

I tried the kafka-console-consumer.sh and kafka-console-producer.sh and it works fine. I was able to see the messages sent by producer in consumer

1) I have downloaded the s3 connector (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html)

2)unzipped the files on to /home/ec2-user/plugins/

3)Created connect-standalone.properties with following contents

```
bootstrap.servers=<my brokers>
plugin.path=/home/ec2-user/kafka-plugins
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

4)Created s3-sink.properties with following contents.

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=<My Topic>
s3.region=us-east-1
s3.bucket.name=vk-ingestion-dev
s3.part.size=5242880
flush.size=1
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
schema.compatibility=NONE
```

When I run the connect-standlone.sh with above two prop files, it is waiting for sometime and throwing the following error.

```
[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:237)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[2019-10-22 19:28:36,789] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:237)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited.
[2019-10-22 19:28:36,796] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:124)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:81)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:58)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Are there any security things that I need to look for ?

Comment: Connect has SSL configs, just like the consumer https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs

Comment: That worked...Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the following ssl config it worked.

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

After adding the above params, connector started with no errors but the data is not uploading to s3.

Adding producer and consumer config param seperately worked.

Example:

```
producer.security.protocol=SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks

consumer.security.protocol=SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to AWS MSK. Exactly to which files should the above producer and consumer entries be added.I am trying to create the Connector via the console to begin with

Comment: Also did you create the truststore files yourself and place them into the /tmp folder under the unzipped plugin folder?